# Spring JavaMailSender: recipient set as "default"

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

It is my first question, so i would like to keep it simple.
I have a problem with JavaMailSender from Spring Framework version 4.1.8.RELEASE. It appears that for a particular SMTP it does not add recipient to the message. I want to mention that we use the same solution in our other projects and it always worked. Since now, there were no problems with recipients.

Here is code example how we setup recipient(setupRecipients method):

```
String emailTo = entity.getEmailTo();
Preconditions.checkNotNull( !Strings.isNullOrEmpty( emailTo ) );
emailTo = emailTo.replace( ",", " " );
emailTo = emailTo.replace( ";", " " );
InternetAddress[] emails = InternetAddress.parse( emailTo );

for ( InternetAddress address : emails )
    address.validate();

for ( InternetAddress address : emails )
    messageHelper.setTo( address.getAddress() );

if ( !Strings.isNullOrEmpty( bcc ) )
    messageHelper.addBcc( bcc );
```

Here is example how we send an email(where mailSender is of type JavaMailSender):

```
    MimeMessage message = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();

    try {
        MimeMessageHelper e = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "utf-8");
        e.setFrom(this.from);
        message.setSubject(this.createSubject(entity));
        this.setupRecipients(entity, e);
        this.setupBody(entity, e);
        this.setupAttachments(entity, e);
        this.setupInlines(entity, e);
        this.mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (IOException | MessagingException var4) {
        Throwables.propagate(var4);
    }
```

When i try to send an email with that special SMTP, i get this response:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; 
  nested exception is:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <default>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address
 ; message exception details (1) are:
    Failed message 1:
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
    nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <default>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1196)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:584)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:433)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at packagename.EmailExporter.export(EmailExporter.java:57)
    at packagename.ExportJobImpl$ExportCallback.onResult_aroundBody0(ExportJobImpl.java:86)
    at packagename.ExportJobImpl$ExportCallback$AjcClosure1.run(ExportJobImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
    at packagename.ExportJobImpl$ExportCallback.onResult(ExportJobImpl.java:81)
    at packagename.ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.lambda$iterate$9(ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.java:30)
    at packagename.ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl$$Lambda$31/1744828123.processRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor.extractData(JdbcTemplate.java:1607)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:752)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767)
    at packagename.ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.iterate_aroundBody0(ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.java:28)
    at packagename.ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl$AjcClosure1.run(ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
    at packagename.ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.iterate(ExportableEntityEnumeratorImpl.java:27)
    at packagename.ExportJobImpl.run(ExportJobImpl.java:50)
    at packagename.MultiExportJobImpl.run(MultiExportJobImpl.java:42)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <default>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1094)
    ... 38 more
```

Here is the list of what we tried:

1. First of all, we have consulted SMTP provider; however, their answer was that recipient is set as "default" and nothing else. We also requested logs but since then they did not provide them(it is not ours SMTP but still they did not provide them even to the owner).
2. Secondly, when i tried to configure JavaMail with Spring and send email locally with the use of my development machine instead of the server our application usually runs on, it worked as intended. Also SMTP has no problems with sending an email when configured with for ex. Thunderbird.
3. When we switched their SMTP with our SMTP on the server, it works.

Conclusion is that the problem must be either in the server configuration, between server and SMTP or SMTP. However i have no idea what might actually cause it.

Comment: Instead of `messageHelper.setTo( address.getAddress() );` try `messageHelper.setTo( address);` saves Spring to do a translation again. Also instead of `setTo` shouldn't you be using `addTo`? Just in case there are multiple addresses? Also a duplicate for loop seems inefficient. You could use a single one.

Comment: I tried messageHelper.setTo( address); and addTo but result is the same. It always sets default as recipient.

Comment: Then there must be an address in there which triggers that behavior.

Comment: For testing purposes i use only one address, which works on other SMTP. It is also not blocked. I have logged it before and after setting recipient. It shows correct value but still sends "default"

Comment: If the address is a FQN then the SMTP server must do something too it, or maybe a conflicting mail jar. Trying to figure this out with the specific setup is probably not going to work, so you have to replicate the server and setup as well.

Comment: Is it possible that SMTP that is setup on this server may interfere with another app that uses same SMTP on the same server?

Comment: It looks like i have found an answer. Culprit was **messageHelper.addBcc( bcc );**. It needs more testing but i'm sure there was a problem, because when i commented this line, email had no problem to be delivered. I will post it as an answer when i make more in dept check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found **what caused a problem** with sending an email. However i don't know why it happens.

Message can't be send and gets "**default**" for a recipient when we add BCC or CC address to **MessageHelper**. I have tried different means to do it **addBcc, setBcc, addCc, setCc** but all of them produce same result. It is very strange and i can't really find explanation.

## **UPDATE:**

We have found an actual culprit. Address used in bcc got value **default**, which of course wasn't logged and validated(such a mistake). However most interesting was the fact that bcc got value **default** even after being set to other correct address, because of annotation **@Autowired**. Funny thing Spring didn't threw out an exception even though we did not declare any value it could be wired to.